# Effect of metal resistivity on the characteristic impedance of microstrip line

Tags: impedance, microstrip, line

We know that the characteristic impedance of a microstrip line is given as follows:

[image]

In general the metal resistivity is so small that Z0 can be taken as sqrt(L/C). But if the metal resisitivity is not that small? Then according to the equation, this resistivity should affect the Z0. Is it true?

I did simple Agilent Genesys simulations of microstrip lines to see the effect of the metal resistivity on Z0 but surprisingly it didn't affect Z0. When I increase the metal resistivity, it only increases the attenuation. Any idea and help is appreciated.

Comment: Really good question. Is there a practical application for this?

Comment: Are you saying you don't believe the 'Telegrapher's Equation?' Or that you didn't use a large enough range of R to see any effect on Z0, above numerical noise like rounding? Or you don't think Genesys models surface resistivity properly? Or that your 'simple' simulation was too simple and left something out? Try instead modelling several short bits of transmission line connected with small resistors, so a lumped approximation with perfect components to the lossy transmission line, and then see whether there's an effect. How did you attempt to measure Z0 anyhow?

Comment: @RolfOstergaard, I don't know any application of this but why not?

Comment: @Neil_UK, I am OK with telegrapher's equation but I couldn't see the effect of changing the metal resistivity on Z0 in Genesys. I'll try your idea of putting dummy resistors in between and notify here.

Comment: A series R sends the impedance complex. How are you detecting the Z0? If you are looking at the magnitude of Z0, it will take quite a large imaginary component to be noticable. You may be better off measuring the phase of Z0, more sensitive.

Comment: Just fyi, the surface roughness also can really affect the trace resistance as well as all the RF energy is flowing in only a thin surface layer (skin effect and all that)

Comment: @Neil_UK, I use the following formula for the extraction of Z0: Z0 = 50*(1 + S11)/(1 - S11) (http://www.edaboard.com/thread143108.html). I'll switch to CST MWS as I am not sure of the Genesys results.

Comment: Is genesys giving you the S11 directly, as a complex number, or as magnitude only? I tend to use straight SPICE, so have to simulate a directional coupler as well, and then compute reflected/incident to get S11.

Comment: @Neil_UK it gives only magnitude as far as I can see. Therefore I am trying to get the complex S11 from CST MWS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a microstrip then it's likely that you are dealing with frequencies in the tens of MHz upwards. Let's use 100 MHz as an example and let's take the example of L being 250 nH per metre and C being 100 pF per metre. Together they produce a characteristic impedance of \$\sqrt{250/0.1}\$ = 50 ohms.

So how much is the impedance of 250 nH at 100 MHz - do the sums and you'll get 157 ohms.

So, if you increase your resistance per metre to something approaching or in excess of this then you are going to see changes to the impedance. It all boils down to how far you increased the resistance per metre and how you measured (or judged) the value of characteristic impedance.

I suspect that you went nowhere near 100 ohms per metre because the resistivity of a copper track 1 metre long would be about 1 ohm or less.